# LinqPad does not remember connections

Tags: linqpad

My hard drive crashed.  As I setup my new one, I am noticing that that I have to setup LinqPad everytime I open it.

I am adding OData connections (WCF DS).

I thought this was automatic, but it does not work.  (I downloaded and re-installed again today just to be sure I did not have an old version.)

Is there anything I can do to encourage LinqPad to remember my connections?

Comment: Just to be sure: is the "Remember this connection" box (when you add a connection) checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad saves connection details to ConnectionsV2.xml in %appdata%\LINQPad. Could there be a permissions issue or something preventing this file from being updated?

Comment: ConnectionsV2.xml has been corrupted (showed a bunch of binary when I opened it).  I deleted it and it all worked.  Thanks for the Help!  (And THANK YOU for LinqPad!)